# Mosquitto bridge with OpenSSL

Tags: linux, openssl, mosquitto, secure-element

I have an embedded Linux system with MQTT through a local broker.
Applications act as MQTT clients to the local broker which is set up as a bridge to a cloud broker.

To enable TLS between the local and cloud broker there are options in mosquitto.conf such as `bridge_certfile` which use keys on the file system, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852800/mqtt-bridge-with-ssl) and the [Mosquitto documentation](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html).

How can I setup the Mosquitto bridge to use **OpenSSL** for TLS, to enable the use of a Secure Element for private key storage?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the secure element is a TPM2 modules.

You can use the `tls_engine` mosquitto.conf option to enable the tpm

```
tls_engine tpm2tss
```

Then use normal `bridge_keyfile` to point to the key handle file. you will also need to set `tls_keyform engine`

You might also need the `tls_engine_kpass_sha1` option to supply the private key passphrase.

I suggest you look at the doc for the `tpm2tss` docs here: https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss-engine

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Does `tls_engine` work for bridge connections?

Comment: What makes you think it won't?

Comment: i think not working. tls_engine for incoming connections. But brige for outgoing. I could not make it running, although successfull tpm library and other operations are success.